# WinUI 3 Access LocalState Folder

Tags: winui-3

I try to migrate my UWP Application to WinUI3. I use SQLite for persistence and so far the DB file was in the Folder "AppData\Local[Package]\LocalState". But new the file is created under "AppData\Local[Package]\LocalCache\Local".
The code to create path is the between both applications:

```
var databasePath =
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        "moneyfox3.db");
```

When I look at the path that is generated by that in debug it is something like "C:\user[user]\AppData\Local". So the runtime seems to make a virtual file structure since the app is sandboxed which makes sense. But is there a way to change the path where that virtual file structure is created? Or is there a way to access the LocalState folder so that I can migrate the db file over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` property should give you the absolute path to the LocalState folder.

As a side note, an MSIX packaged desktop app is not really "sandboxed" but it writes to its own virtual registry and application data folder as explained in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/msix-container?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: That's a XAMARIN concept. It's got no analog in WinUI can I can find.

Comment: What? Nothing in my answer is related to Xamarin.

Comment: After 1 weeks attempt to write to Run key in registry, even with Win32 api and failed, I found the key information you here, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer. The **Environment** class contains the location of the local  application data that Windows Store applications can use.

```
// This serializes the account's credentials.
var applicationDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```