# How to create a folder in the AppDataDirectory for a Dotnet Maui app?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

With UWP one would use ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync().

I can find no maui equivalent. The objective is to have seperate user folders (ie user1, user2) within the app data directory.

Comment: That is platform-specific, so won't have a Maui equivalent. If you want that functionality on Windows, you'll put "WinUI 3" code in "Windows" folder of your project. Similar to [WinUI 3 Access LocalState Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70991801/199364), though that example is before Maui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows) about the file system in the maui?

For the windows platform in the maui:

> FileSystem.AppDataDirectory
> Returns the LocalFolder directory that is backed up to the cloud.

You can try to create the user folder by the following code:

```
string mainDir =System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "user1") ;
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDir);
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Creates the folder on Windows and Android. I don't know about IOS etc. I was trying to create the folder without CreateDirectory!

Comment: For the IOS: FileSystem.AppDataDirectory
Returns the Library directory that is backed up by iTunes and iCloud. @PeterDC